# slideshare web scrape page views python

Tags: java, python, html

Hey guys For my school project I need to web scrape slideshare.net for page views using python. However, it wont let me scrape the page views of the user name (which the professor specifically told us to scrape)  for example if I go to slideshare.net/Username on the bottom there will be a page view counter when i go into page source the code is

```
 <span class="noWrap"> xxxx views </span>
```

when I plug this into python as

```
 <span class="noWrap"> (.+?) </span>
```

Nothing happens all I get is [] in the out put window

## HERE IS FULL CODE -

```
import urllib
import re

symbolfile = open("viewpage.txt")

symbolslist = symbolfile.read()

for symbol in symbolslist:
    print symbol
htmlfile = urllib.urlopen("http://www.slideshare.net/xxxxxxx")

htmltext = htmlfile.read()

regex = ' <span class="noWrap">(.+?)</span>'
regex_a = '<title>(.+?)</title>'

pattern = re.compile(regex)
pattern_a = re.compile(regex_a)

view = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
view_a = re.findall(pattern_a,htmltext)

print (view, view_a)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `xxxx views ` ? whats `x`?

Answer (score 0):

You have a space at the start of your regex string, so it will only match if there's (at least) one space before the `<span`...

So instead of

`regex = ' <span class="noWrap">(.+?)</span>'`

try

`regex = '<span class="noWrap">(.+?)</span>'`

or even better

`regex = r'<span class="noWrap">\s*(.+?)\s*</span>'`

Raw strings like `r'stuff'` are preferred for regex use, so you don't have to escape too much stuff inside the regex string.

The `\s` patterns will consume spaces so your won't need to use `strip()` on the data you capture with `findall()`.

I should also mention that `pattern.findall(text)` is a bit nicer syntax than `re.findall(pattern, text)`.

Answer (score -1):

Although this in not an technically an answer you will need to change your regular expression. I suggest you look at the python regex chapters.

What I will tell you is that your line

```
regex = ' <span class="noWrap">(.+?)</span>'
```

will not match what you are after based on the output of the webpage since there are carriage returns in the html and your regex will not match these, hence the empty list when you run your script.

Or you could remove the carriage returns before you run your regex with

```
htmltext = htmltext.replace("\n","")
```

Comment: The End Of Line (EOL) markers aren't a problem for this regex. FWIW, "\n" == chr(10) is a linefeed; a carriage return is "\r" == chr(13). *nix uses "\n" for EOL; Windows uses "\r\n". And I think Mac uses "\r", or at least, it used to. "\n" is preferred for HTML, but both EOL styles are tolerated by browsers.